# what is the relationship of dtd and ent file?

Tags: xml, database, dtd

I down load a DTD.zip from Pubmed central,a database special in Medicine. It is not a Dtd file,it consists of folders,many dtd files,many ent files .

the dtd file: ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/pub/archive_dtd/publishing/

Answer (score 7):

What you're seeing is a modularized DTD. The DTD is made up of many different modules (usually .ent files or .mod files) so that pieces of the DTD can be reused or ignored/included easily.

These different modules are normally referenced from within a base DTD by using parameter entities.

For example, an XML instance will still reference a single DTD with it's DOCTYPE declaration, but that DTD will have parameter entity declarations/references to other files that contain declarations for element, attlist, entity, etc.

Using "journal-publishing-dtd-3.0.zip" from your link as another example, you could have an XML instance that validates to "journalpublishing3.dtd", but if you look at that DTD you'll see that there are references to 2 other modules ("journalpubcustom-modules3.ent" and "modules3.ent") which themselves reference even more modules.